# Read and print with FORTRAN

Tags: function, fortran, gfortran, fortran95

I need to write a Fortran program which can read and print a .dat file.

(A file homework_6.dat contains book records: Name (up to 25 characters), publish year (4 digit integer), price (6 digit real), ISBN (13 digit integer). Write a program to read the file (homework_6.dat) and print out (on screen or into another file) the details in the following format:

```
                                     Publish   
          Name                        Year    ($)        ISBN
       -------------------------      ----   ------     -------------
       Principles of Combustion       2005    107.61     9780471046899
       An Introduction to Comb        2011    193.99     9780073380193 
       Guide to Fortran               2009     71.95     9781848825420
       Modern Fortran Explain         2011    100.00     9780199601417
       Introduction to Program        2012    200.00     9780857292322)
```

Here what i write

```
program dat
implicit none
character (len=25) :: Name
integer :: i, publish_year, ISBN
real :: price 
open(unit=7, file="homework_6.dat", status="old", action="readwrite")
do i=1, 10
read (unit=7,fmt="(a25,i4,f3.2,i13)") Name, publish_year, price, ISBN
write (unit=7,fmt="(a25,i4,f3.2,i13)") Name, publish_year, price, ISBN
end do
close(unit=7)
end program dat
```

But Fortran says there is an error at line 8

I don't know what to do :(

Sonya (ITU)

**--edit--**

So i tried to write a program, but i still have error after the execution

```
program dat
    implicit none
    character (len=25) :: Name
    character (len=13) :: ISBN
    integer :: i, publish_year
    real :: price 
    open(unit=10, file="homework_6.dat", status="old", action="readwrite")
    open(unit=11, file="output_hw6.dat")
    !Comment: these below 3 lines are for skipping 3 heading your input
    read(10,*)
    read(10,*)
    read(10,*)
    do i=1, 10
    read (10,*) Name, publish_year, price, ISBN
    write (11,1) Name, publish_year, price, ISBN
    1 format(a25,2x,i4,2x,f3.2,2x,a13)
    end do
    close(unit=10)
    end program dat
```

I have an error in line 14.
ERROR 52, invalid character in field
 DAT -  in file homework.f95 at line 14 [+01b3]

Comment: you should post the error message you saw as well.

Comment: What error? Runtime, or compiletime? Write it here.

Comment: You need to do three reads to skip over the three header lines in the file.

Comment: The error 
Error 52 Invalid character in field 
in file at line 8 (+013a)

Comment: Its not a runtine or complile error

Comment: Can somebody write his own program, because mine doest work 
and i don"t know what to do

Comment: Follow M.S.B.'s suggestion, you must skip the first lines using just `read(7,*)`, also write the output to the screen to a preconnected unit `*` and not the same you use for input.

Comment: Thank, you, i undertand why i have to skip the line
but i still have an error fo the read in the do

Comment: you have some errors in your `fmt` specification. You need to account for spaces, and for the price, `f3.2` means read 3 characters, of which 2 are after the decimal (effectively reading just the decimal point and what's after it here). you'll need at least `f6.2`. But, a better way is to use list-directed input and just specify `*` instead of any custom formats, like so: `read(7,*) Name, publish_year, price, ISBN`.

Comment: Yes, i change it for read(7,*) , but i still have an error for this line !
Beauce of spaces between words.
What can i put instead of the * ?

Comment: Upon re-reading your question, one thing is not clear to me: is your first code listing the contents of the input data file, or is it an example of the desired output and is the input file just raw data? Your other code currently seems to suggest that you are just copying lines, which could be done much more easily, without most of the formatting hassle...

Comment: He says its the same, however that cant be (or could be the cause of the trouble) as his names go well past 25 charaters, even assumeing 4 spaces added for code formatting. User19xx open your input file and count how many spaces are actually a the beginning of each line. I'm assuming by now you've realiesed you swithed the "*"and 1 in the read/write statements, (or maybe not?). All that said "please debug my code" is not a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading with the list directed format, but this will not work. There are spaces in the book names and the compiler is not going to find, where it ends, and where the year begins.

You must use a format. A tip: use a format string in the read statement, not a format statement with a label. The format will be similar to the output one you have.

Another hint, your output format for price is too short. I recommend f6.2.

Comment: Humm .. ok i need to use "string" but i don't know how

Comment: This is not the point. instead of the label, you can put the format directly there as `read (*,'(f5.1)')` but this is equivalent to the label to format, it will not solve your program. You must find the right format.

Comment: I was able to run it OK, but I am not going to post the exact solution here now.

Comment: I don't how to solve my problem .. 
i use 
1 format(a25,2x,i4,2x,f6.2,2x,a13)
I thought it was sufficient ...
I really don't know what to do ...

Comment: You must use a format also for read, not only for write. Enough for me is `read(10,'(azz,izz,fzz.z,azz)') Name, publish_year, price, ISBN` where z are numbers you should find.

Comment: I write 
read (10,'(a25,6x,i4,4x,f6.2,5x,a13)') Name, publish_year, price, ISBN
Still the same error

Comment: That means you have to find better numbers. Did you count the spaces at the beginning of the lines?

Comment: read (10,'(7x,a25,6x,i4,3x,f6.2,5x,a13)') Name, publish_year, price, ISBN

i count all spaces .. i don't understand the error now "Error 57, attempt to read past end-of-file"

Comment: @user1949518: You have to either explicitly list the spaces in your `read` format statement, or make the four fields you are reading wide enough so that you can omit spacing. For example you can read the first two fields with `'(3x, a25, 5x, i4)'` or as `'(a28, i9)'`. In the latter case, the string will include 3 leading spaces, but leading/trailing blanks in numeric data are ignored by default.

Comment: In the original file, there are 7 spaces before the first word (not 3)
i tried with and without *x, like you say ... but i still have the error !

Comment: i will edit my first post, because there are not the same number of spaces

Comment: I edit my first post, if there are errors just because of spaces, can you give me your read line ?

Comment: @user1949518: The end-of-file error is not related to the format and could not be clearer: you are trying to read more data than is in the file. Namely, 10 lines where your example contains 5. Avoid this by reading an appropriate number or by testing for the EOF before you read the next line. Also, you may have noted that people are hesitant to fully answer homework questions, with the intention of leaving some of the thinking to the student. I have to agree though that Fortran's formatted I/O is cumbersome ;-).

Comment: ohhhh ! I undersant now where was the mistake ! In the do loop ! Mine was i=1, 10 but i just have 5 lines ! Ok !
It's been 3 days that I'm trying to solve this exercise.
thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace unit=7 by 7, in line 8. But the problem is you are reading from homework_6.dat and writing in the same file. You can open new file or output on the screen. I have modified your code to read from the data file you have shown assuming it has 3 lines of heading before the data.

```
    program dat
    implicit none
    character (len=25) :: Name
    integer :: i, publish_year, ISBN
    real :: price 
    open(unit=7, file="homework_6.dat", status="old", action="readwrite")
    open(unit=8, file="output_hw6.dat")
    !Comment: these below 3 lines are for skipping 3 heading your input                 
    read(7,*)
    read(7,*)
    read(7,*)
    do i=1, 10
    read (7,*) Name, publish_year, price, ISBN
    write (8,1) Name, publish_year, price, ISBN
    1 format(a25,2x,i4,2x,f3.2,2x,i13)
    end do
    close(unit=7)
    end program dat
```

Your hw problem can easily be solved by consulting any beginners fortran book.

Comment: I understand why i need to use 3 read (to skip the 3 lines)
but i have this error 
error 283 - DUMMY must appear in a type declaration because IMPLICIT NONE has been used
Compilation failed.

Comment: when i put dummy in character, i still have an error 
 DAT -  in file freeformat4.f95 at line 14 [+0204]

Comment: Yes I should have given dummy variable a type. You can just delete the dummy variable and just leave the line as read(7,*)                        make sure that you skip the required lines in data file before you begin to read your actual data, otherwise you will still have errors while reading.

Comment: Ok
I have 3 lines to skip, but i still have the error for the "read" in the do loop

Comment: the .dat file is exactly the same as what i write (Name, publish year ...)
so i have 3 lines to skip